# Why am I offered 20.04 on a 32 bit machine?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, 32-bit

I just got the offer to upgrade to 20.04.1 on Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS (an alert with an Upgrade Now button).

I was under the impression that 20.04 wasn't available for 32 bit machines and that I would receive no more upgrade offers since it would shorten my support period.

Why do I get the opportunity to upgrade?

Comment: If you were offered that upgrade, I'd suggest you file a bug as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1845690 was intended to prevent that from occurring. (I'd suggest filing a new bug using ubuntu-bug update-manager and reference the bug I mentioned in your description; it'll save someone from needing to look it up).  Note it's been reported here before, but when users tend to run update-manager again, they often get https://launchpadlibrarian.net/475882446/bug-1845690-verification.png or equivalent the second & subsequent times.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for confirming that it's unintended behavior, and for the extra information.

Answer (score 5):

If you were offered that upgrade, I'd suggest you file a bug as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1845690 was intended to prevent that from occurring.

You could file a new bug using

`ubuntu-bug update-manager`

and reference the bug I mentioned in your description; (*it'll save someone from needing to look it up*).

Note it's been reported here before, but when users tend to run `update-manager` again, they often get https://launchpadlibrarian.net/475882446/bug-1845690-verification.png *or equivalent* the second & subsequent times.

---

Since this issue still impacts users, I'll provide more...

The bug report in my prior comment was believed to have fixed the issue, alas didn't. A new bug was raised https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1901725 which has/is being monitored, however given there are no negative consequences (*except minor confusion by users*), it's not high priority. On some boxes the message does not re-appear, on others it will (*depending on config & answers given to prompts, and repeatedly too*)

If this still troubles you, likely your best response is follow the bug report (re-filed report being https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1901725), hit the "*affects me too*" to raise heat on the bug report, and even better leave a comment detailing how it directly impact you. This will get the most likely best response, as currently it records as only impacting 2 users only (*which are a Canonical employee & a tester+end-user; not much heat really*)

Comment: I have done some testing of this on x86/i386 boxes (pentium 4, pentium M etc) and whilst this upgrade message maybe concerning/confusing for end-users, I could not have it create issues no matter how I answered.  My concentration is *flavors* I'm involved with (primarily Lubuntu, Xubuntu too) but I assume it'll respond the same if you use other *flavors* or main Ubuntu  (I've never tried GNOME3 on a x86 box; and have no desire to)

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu (& other *flavors*) offer 18.04 for 32 bit platform. They will be supported until 2021-April (with the base system still getting upgraded packages until 2023-April).

It is a bug and after an install you will get `i386 is not supported` error. Don't install it

Comment: Lubuntu is a *flavor* of Ubuntu, as such it only comes with 3 years of support for LTS releases. Refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ or http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ which clearly states "*flavours will be supported for 3 years*" meaning support is until 2021-April. That's a long way short of 2028.  5 years is main Ubuntu *yy.mm* releases (extendable via ESM), with 10 years applying to *yy* or *snap* based releases such as Ubuntu Core 18 (it's this release that is supported until 2028).

Comment: Lubuntu & Xubuntu had 18.10 releases in i386, and both included *alpha* ISOs into the 19.04 cycle (which had upgraded-packages the full life of 19.04).  Many *flavors* actually had 18.04 releases, I helped text Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu for the latest 18.04.5 release August-2020 but other *flavors* had releases too.  http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/415/builds

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it's unintended. As @guiverc pointed out, 18.04 is offered by more than Lubuntu, so I will assume you meant to say 20.04.